# How can I sort my data based on ratings using react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

My database looks like this. I want to create a filter that will return top-rated data

```
{
_id:61f24397e8192a0a5994aaa8
title:"title"
expense:"50"
ratings:"5"
date:"2022-01-28"
time:"10"
category:"k"
location:"1010"
description:"101010"
}
```

I tried to like this but got an error `Sidebar.js:14 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: parseInt(...).sort is not a function`

```
useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/blogs`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                const approvedBlogs = data.filter(blogs => parseInt(blogs.ratings).sort((a, b) => b - a))
                // const approvedBlogs = data.filter(blogs => blogs.ratings === '5')
                setBlogs(approvedBlogs)
            })
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
    }, [])
```

Comment: Typo, you try to sort an integer, not the filtered array: `.filter(blogs => parseInt(blogs.ratings).sort((a, b) => b - a))` should be `.filter((blogs) => parseInt(blogs.ratings)).sort((a, b) => b - a)`

Comment: What do you mean by top-rated data? Only the data with a rating of "5"? Only the data with the highest rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly sort data without filtering

```js
useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/blogs`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                 data.sort((a, b) => {
                     const parsedA = parseInt(a.ratings, 10);
                     const parsedB = parseInt(b.ratings, 10);
                     return parsedA > parsedB ? -1 : 1; // for descending sort inverse -1 and 1
                 });
                setBlogs(data)
            })
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you're are trying to sort an integer instead of an array.

*Change this line:*

```
 const approvedBlogs = data.filter(blogs => parseInt(blogs.ratings).sort((a, b) => b - a))
```

*To this:*

```
const approvedBlogs = data.sort((a, b) => (+a.ratings > +b.ratings ? -1 : 1));
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter` to throw away blogs you don't want anymore (like in commented line). After that, use `.sort` to order data by ratings.
It should look like:

```
const approvedBlogs = data.filter(blogs => blogs.ratings === '5')
                           .sort( (a, b) => return parseInt(b.rating) - parseInt(a.rating)
```